# Azure caching of of securitytoken

Tags: .net, session, caching, azure, wif

How do you setup shared caching with a dedicated cache worker role and multiple instances of a webrole?  dotnet 4.5.1 mvc 5.1.

I have a sessiontoken i'm trying to use for authentication/authorization.  The token has a long validto/from times.

```
                var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(principal)
                {
                    IsReferenceMode = true,
                };

                FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.
                    SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(sessionToken, true);
```

I added a cache worker role and configured it by enabling cache and setting it to dedicated.  It created a default named cache setting with 30min sliding window LRU policy.

In my web.config of my webroles

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SessionProvider" 
             type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" 
             cacheName="default" 
             dataCacheClientName="default" 
             applicationName="MyApp"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

  <dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="CacheWorkerRole" />
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

It seems to work with one instance, but fails when I introduce more.  It seems to work for a minute or two then it vanishes. Like one instance is not aware of the cache.  Even if I click around a bit to try to get to the first instance it appears to be gone.

It seems that I can add/read things from the cache manually from each instance.

I must have WIF or Caching misconfigured.

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if i change the sessiontoken to the following code snip it works.  Not sure if thats the right thing or not.

```
      var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(principal) 
        {
            IsPersistent = true,
        };
```